# access an iis web page from c#(ssis) which requires authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, ssis

I have a web site on a host which runs IIS and serves php pages and requires staff to login with their AD details and this works well.

Now i need to run a process from SSIS that runs a c# bit of code to call a url which returns some csv data and is saved to a local file, however I can not access the web page due to the authentication requirement. Is their a way to set these details prior to calling the url in c#.

thanks, the code to call the url in c# is below

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadFile(l_url, l_file);
```

Comment: myWebClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User","pass","domain");

Comment: myWebClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass","domain);